# ValidationEngine doesn't work for a form dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, jquery-validation-engine

After create a form on the fly the validationEngine doesn't work anymore

```
      $(window).load(function($) {

        var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.setAttribute('id', 'xform');

        var lbl_usr = document.createElement('label');

        var input_usr = document.createElement('input');
        input_usr.setAttribute('id', 'user');
        input_usr.setAttribute('name', 'user');
        input_usr.setAttribute('class', 'user-txt');

        var submit = document.createElement('input');
        submit.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
        submit.setAttribute("value", "login");
        submit.setAttribute('id', 'login');

        form.appendChild(lbl_usr);
        form.appendChild(input_usr);
        form.appendChild(submit);

        var divLog = document.getElementById('log');
        divLog.appendChild(form);

       });
```

And I have configured the ValidationEngine as showed bellow:

```
    // I have tried attach to the form the validationEngine
    // on document ready, load and without both but it doesn't working            
    $("#xform").validationEngine('attach',{
          onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
             $("#xform").bind('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
             });
        },
        maxErrorsPerField: 1,
        custom_error_messages : {
            // Custom Error Messages for Validation Types
            '.user-txt': {
               'minSize': {
                 'message': "less than required."
               },
               'required': {
                 'message': "required"
               }
            }
        }
     });

     $(document).on('click', '#login', function (e) {
        $('#xform').validationEngine('validate');
     });

     // I have tried this but without success for a dynamically form
     // created, for a static form this works fine
     $('#login').click(function() {
          $('#xform').validationEngine('validate');
     });

  });
```

I don't know why this doesn't work and what is going wrong with this code...

Some help would be great

Thanks

Comment: At the point of execution so called attaching the validation engine, $('#xform') is empty object. Because it hasn't been created yet. Does the console show any error stating that fact?

Comment: Nope, console doesn't show any kind of error about it. But with the  $(document).on('click', '#login' is expected that the #login submit btn will receive the event later and when the form is available in DOM, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your code anything but the validator. On what condition your form is validated? Just add this line (posabsolute's jquery validation engine capable of reading options from HTML5 data attributes):

```
input_usr.setAttribute('data-validation-engine', 'validate[required]');
```

[Here](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#validators) list of validators you can use between square brackets in above line.